# Suppose $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is an integer. Show that if $p \mid a^n$, then $p^n \mid a^n$ for any $n \geq 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I know that if $p \mid a^n$, I can say $a^n = pr$ for some integer $r$, you can also conclude that $\gcd(p, a^n) = p$, but I'm not sure how to use that information if I even can to show that $p^n \mid a^n$.

Comment: What do you already know, gcds, or Bezout or Euclid's lemma, or $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a$ or $\,p\mid b,\,$ or FTA or $\,\ldots\,?$ Please give some context so we can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Can you show that, for arbitrary positive $n$,  $b^n \mid a^n \iff b\mid a$?

Answer (score 4):

You probably already have the fact that $p$ is prime and $p\mid ab$ implies that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.  You can use this to "descend" from $p\mid a^n$ to $p\mid a^{n-1}$ or $p\mid a$, then $p\mid a^{n-2}$ or $p\mid a$ etc., until you have $p\mid a$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: What is $\gcd(p,a)$? $1$ or $p$?